# Multi-column lists in Bootstrap/Foundation

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists, multiple-columns

I am trying to figure out the best way to create vertical multi-column lists in a grid framework like Bootstrap or Foundation.  I already know how to do this in a couple of ways, but the way I want it I am not sure is possible to do with just CSS.  I need the `li` tags to come directly after the `ul` tag without a `col-*-*` divs between.

To best describe what I want, I'll first show most people would roughly go about a 3 column list:

```
<ul class="row">
    <li class="col-sm-4">A</li>
    <li class="col-sm-4">B</li>
    <li class="col-sm-4">C</li>
    <li class="col-sm-4">D</li>
    <li class="col-sm-4">E</li>
    <li class="col-sm-4">F</li>
</ul>
```

The problem here is that the output will not be vertically read, and that is what I want.  This would produce more of a horizontal list where the columns are not in the desired order like this:

```
A    B    C
D    E    F
```

Now here is my solution (not good enough):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="row">
            <ul>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <li>A</li>
                    <li>B</li>
                    <li>C</li>
                    <li>D</li>
                    <li>E</li>
                    <li>F</li>
                    <li>G</li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <li>H</li>
                    <li>I</li>
                    <li>J</li>
                    <li>K</li>
                    <li>L</li>
                    <li>M</li>
                    <li>N</li>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <li>O</li>
                    <li>P</li>
                    <li>Q</li>
                    <li>R</li>
                    <li>S</li>
                    <li>T</li>
                    <li>U</li>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way I get the desired order result of:

```
A    H    O
B    I    P
C    J    Q
D    K    R
E    L    S
F    M    T
G    N    U
```

But it's not good enough for me because the `li` tags do not immediately follow after the `ul` tag.

**Is there any way I can accomplish this 3 column list without separating groups of `li` tags from one another?**

Note:  I'd also like to point out the benefit of doing it like example #1 which would give you automatic columns so that's great if you're working on an app or with PHP.  I would hopefully like to keep that functionality if possible.

Thank you in advance to any assistance.  This is tough to describe so please ask me a question to clarify if you don't understand.  Thanks!

Comment: Unless you have some specific need for all the `<li>` tags to be children of the same `<ul>`, I would just have one `<ul>` per `col-sm-4` div

Comment: This is pretty much what I am doing in the second code example, without having to define multiple `ul` elements.  However your method could still be a solution because what I really want to do is use the CSS selector `ul > li` and my example would not allow that because the `li`'s are no longer direct children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is what you're trying to do or hopefully it helps you figure out exactly what you're trying to do.

Example 1: `columns` as the `unordered` list class and your content inside the list items.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
      <li class="alert alert-info">A</li>
      <li class="alert alert-info">B</li>
      <li class="alert alert-info">C</li>
      <li class="alert alert-info">D</li>
      <li class="alert alert-info">E</li>
      <li class="alert alert-info">F</li>
      <li class="alert alert-info">G</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
      <li class="alert alert-danger">H</li>
      <li class="alert alert-danger">I</li>
      <li class="alert alert-danger">J</li>
      <li class="alert alert-danger">K</li>
      <li class="alert alert-danger">L</li>
      <li class="alert alert-danger">M</li>
      <li class="alert alert-danger">N</li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="col-sm-4 list-unstyled">
      <li class="alert alert-warning">O</li>
      <li class="alert alert-warning">P</li>
      <li class="alert alert-warning">Q</li>
      <li class="alert alert-warning">R</li>
      <li class="alert alert-warning">S</li>
      <li class="alert alert-warning">T</li>
      <li class="alert alert-warning">U</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example 2: A nested grid with `rows` as the unordered list class and `columns` as list items with your content inside.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="row list-unstyled">
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">A</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">B</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">C</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">D</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">E</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">F</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-info">G</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="row list-unstyled">
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">H</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">I</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">J</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">K</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">L</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">G</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-danger">N</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <ul class="row list-unstyled">
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">O</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">P</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">Q</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">R</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">R</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">T</div>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <div class="alert alert-warning">U</div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```